# PHP - постоянное отставание от реального времени

Tags: php, дата, время

Все функции для работы со временем в `PHP` возвращают время, всегда отличающееся от точного на некоторую величину, вне зависимости от временных зон. Например, сейчас `13:51:03`, а сервер возвращает `13:49:23`. Причём завтра разница во времени будет другой.

Почему так происходит и как сделать так, чтобы время на сервере соответствовало реальному времени?

Comment: Что с синхронизацией времени на этом хосте?

Comment: Это на клиенте смотрите? Если серверное время и клиентское одно и тоже, то эта разница - время от момента когда отработал скрипт, и когда он отобразился на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема, разница во времени азза того что php получает время как только ты обратился с нему. Но сама старница еще не сгенерирована.
Пример код получил время 13:51:03, страница загрузилась за 00:00:03, значит сейчас разница от реального времени будет 3с.

Comment: это еще можно понять, но разница во времени бывает и около 2-х минут, хотя страница уже загрузилась.